# ¬A → B , ¬B ⊢ A

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

1. not A > B :PR
2. not B :PR

PR = Premises
This is the strategy of the Conditional Introduction. On line 3 I'm assuming the antecedent of my goal sentence.

(You don’t have to use this vv but it’s what I’m using for class.)

Conjunction Introduction - /\Im,n
Conjunction Elimination - /\Em
Disjunction Introduction - /Im
Disjunction Elimination - /Em,n-o,p-q
Conditional Introduction - ->Im-n
Conditional Elimination - ->Em,n
Biconditional Introduction - <->Im-n,o-p
Biconditional Elimination - <->Em,n
Negation Introduction - ~Im-n
Negation Elimination - ~Em,n
Explosion - Xm
Indirect Proof - IPm-n
Disjunctive Syllogism - DSm,n
Modus Tollens - MTm,n
Double Negation Elimination - DNEm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> On line 3 I'm assuming the antecedent of my goal sentence.

Rather, assume $\lnot A$, which is the *negation* of your goal sentence, so that you can produce a proof by reduction to absurdity.